# Splunk SDK search query outputs limited information

Tags: splunk, splunk-sdk, splunk-api

I am currently using Splunk SDKs to export data out of Splunk with the following:

```
SPLUNK QUERY: search index=***** sourcetype=*** host={host} earliest={earliest} latest={latest}
```

I have a python script that calls:
`splunk_service.jobs.create(search_query)` and output and store the data on a day by day basis.

The script works fine, however I notice that all the files are of the same size, i.e. 60kb and all the files have `{"text":"Your timerange was substituted based on your search string"}` at the beginning.

I am trying to figure out if the data is being limited and my goal is the get all the data for the time period.

I tried appending `count=0` to the SPLUNK query, however I end up getting zero results when I do so.

I tried running :

```
SPLUNK QUERY: search index=***** sourcetype=*** host={host} earliest={earliest} latest={latest} count=0 offset=0
```

and was expecting all results, however ended up getting 0 results. I was at least getting limited results without the `count=0 offset=0` parameters.